# Finding the Maximum value in this equation.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Maximize $x+y$ on curve $x^4+y^4=1$

$▽f = (1,1)$, $▽g = (4x^3,4y^3)$

---

$(1 = 4x^3λ)y^3$

$ (1= 4y^3λ)x^3$

---

$y^3 = 4x^3y^3λ$

$ x^3 = 4x^3y^3λ$

---

$x^3=y^3$

$x=y$

---

$2x^4 = 1$  $\quad $ $x= \sqrt[4]{\frac 12} $$\quad $$x=- \sqrt[4]{\frac 12} $

Maximize $x+y$ $= 2^{1/4}$

according to the book though it is $2^{3/4}$.

Would anyone know where I have made my miscalculation?

Comment: Your book is wrong. The max is at $x=y=\left(\frac 12\right)^{1/4}$. A quick graph will show this.

Comment: Lagrange multipliers are not properly used. What they say is that the two gradients are proportional (by a multiplier $\lambda$), hence it must be $4x^3=4y^3$. Thus $x=y$ and $1=x^4+y^4=2x^4$. We conclude that the extrema are the points $\pm(a,a)$ with $a=1/2^{1/4}$. The maximum for the positive coordinates, the minimum for the negative ones. Warning: the extrema exist because the curve is compact, hence the cpontinuous function $x+y$ reaches a max and a min. This confirms the plot one can look at.